# innerhtml call javascript function onchange

Tags: javascript, jsp

```
var oCell = newRow.insertCell();
oCell.innerHTML = " <select name='Categories1' onchange="showProd(this.value);"  style='width:100%;'>"
```

Whats wrong with the code? I am not able to call the function showProd()
Please help.

Comment: Syntax error - check your nested quotes.

Comment: Your heading says onchange, you're using onclick? Where does insertCell come from? You're also not using consistent quotation marks - you're using " for the onclick, meaning that this won't be valid and you should be getting errors in your console.

Comment: ohh pardon. I was trying with different ways so accidentally posted wrong question. I am looking for onchange() not onclick().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this and check :

```
oCell.innerHTML = " <select name='Categories1' onClick=showProd("+this.value+");  style='width:100%;'>"
```

Comment: since you looking for onchange replace onclick by onchange above